# Type which has a owned entity and is defined as an owned entity breaks when project is upgraded to EF Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1, owned-types

I have a `Portfolio` and `SampleItem` classes like this:

```
public class Portfolio 
{
        [Required]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public virtual List<SampleItem > SampleItems { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<SampleItem> Sample{
            get{
                return SampleItems;
            }
        }
}

public class SampleItems 
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

When i upgraded project to **.NET Core 3.1**, an exception"

> 'The relationship from 'SampleItem' to 'Portfolio.SampleItems' is not
> supported because the owned entity type 'Portfolio' cannot be on the
> principal side of a non-ownership relationship.'

Portfolio is also defined as owned entity type in another class like this:

```
public class Bill
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "GenId is required")]
        public string GenId { get; set; }

        public Guid PortfolioId { get; set; }
        public virtual Portfolio Portfolio { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my repository context class i have like this:

```
 public virtual DbSet<Bill> Bills{ get; set; }
 public virtual DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
```

I tried so many ways to solve the issue by defining `ownsmany` in repository context class like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Portfolio>().OwnsMany(x => x.SampleItems);
```

but then i get a different exception:

> 'The type 'Portfolio' cannot be configured as non-owned because an
> owned entity type with the same name already exists.'

I cannot figure out how to solve this issue with **EF Core 3.1** and we cannot rollback to **.NET Core 2.x**

Please help me on what i m doing wrong.

Portfolio is never configured as owned type. It is referenced in Bill class through foreign key relationship.

Here is the entire repositorycontext class

```
public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
    {
        public RepositoryContext()
        {
        }
        public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor) : base(options)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public virtual DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Classification> Classifications { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Bill> Bills { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<IntegrationEventLogEntry> IntegrationEventLogs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<LivingExpenseSetting> LivingExpenseSettings { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new IntegrationEventLogEntityTypeConfiguration()); //IMPOPRTANT FOR LOGGING
            var status = BillStatus.Pending.ToString();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Bill>().Property(lst => lst.Created).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Bill>()
                        .Property(p => p.Status)
                        .HasDefaultValue("Pending");
                         
             modelBuilder.Entity<LivingExpenseSetting>();
           
        }
        public override int SaveChanges(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
        {
            OnBeforeSaving();
            return base.SaveChanges(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess);
        }
    }
```

Comment: plesae learn this article: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: Where and how do you configure `Portfolio` as owned entity? The way you reference it from `Bill` (via FK) and the presence of `DbSet<Portfolio>` implies that it *cannot* be owned entity. So most likely EFC 2.x was ignoring your attempt to configure it as owned, and EFC3.x is just giving you an error as it should have been from the beginning. Post the full relevant fluent configuration in order to tell you what was/is wrong with it and how to correct it.

Comment: Yes Portfolio is never configured as owned entity with owner as Bill. Only SampleItems collection is referenced in Portoflio. Now when i upgraded to EF Core 3.1, it gives the exception "'The relationship from 'SampleItem' to 'Portfolio.SampleItems' is not supported because the owned entity type 'Portfolio' cannot be on the principal side of a non-ownership relationship". I am really confused because Portfolio is never configured as owned type but referenced through foreign key relationship in Bill class. This configuration used to work in EF Core 2.2. Here is the repositorycontext class